# How can I wait for n seconds for a named pipe to open?

Tags: c++, linux, named-pipes, polling

I have a program that I want to exit when I can not open a pipe for read, after N (lets say 30) seconds.

My code works with blocking name pipes and I can not change this.

I know about select() and poll() but I can not get them to work without turning my pipes into non-blocking.

This is my code so far:

```
struct pollfd fds[1];
int pol_ret;

fds[0].fd = open(pipe_name, O_RDONLY /* | O_NONBLOCK */);

if (fds[0].fd < 0)
{
    // send_signal_to_parent();
    std::cout << "error while opening the pipe for read, exiting!" << '\n';
    return -1;
}

fds[0].events = POLLIN;

int timeout_msecs = 30000;    //  (30 seconds)
pol_ret = poll(fds, 1, timeout_msecs);

std::cout << "poll returned: "<< pol_ret << '\n';
 if (pol_ret == 0)
 {
     std::cout << "im leaving" << '\n';
     return -1;    
 }
```

How can I wait only for 30 seconds for a pipe to open for read?

I'm running Linux, debian in particular.

Comment: Linux, debian in particular.

Comment: For either _`select()` and `poll()`_ there are variants to wait with specific timeouts specified by you. Also see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494626/c-select-not-waiting-for-timeout-period),

Comment: Please provide at least some example of your code and also explain what exactly isn't working.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know, but I can not figure out how to do it. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Show us the code which doesn't work for you, and explain what is not up to your liking.

Comment: So what happens when you run this code?

Comment: It just waits on open() and poll never returns.

Comment: @GeorgeSp Yup, you need to timeout  `open` too or it'll block indefinitely, waiting for a writing to open it too. Signals+timer are the way to go in that regard. See my answer.

Comment: @GeorgeSp Maybe tag it C also? POSIX functions are C APIs and even in your example you're not using a lot of the ++. (You might get a friendlier reception with C programmers too.)

Comment: @PSkocik indeed I could use C tag probably. I will go with your approach on the answer below and see what happens. It is a clever workaround that I haven't seen before, I wish I have thought of it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup up a timer with a signal handler and wait call open on the fifo.
If the open fails with `errno=EINTR` and your handler ran, the `open` call was  interrupted by your timer, i.e., it timed out.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t abort_eh;
void handler(int Sig)
{
    abort_eh = 1;
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa,0);

    //try to ensure the fifo exists
    (void)mkfifo("fifo",0600);

    //open with a timeout of 1s
    alarm(1);

    int fd;
    do{
        if (0>(fd=open("fifo",O_RDONLY)))
            if(errno==EINTR){
                if(abort_eh) return puts("timed out"),1;
                else continue; //another signal interrupted it, so retry
            }else return perror("open"),1;
    }while(0);

    alarm(0); //cancel timer
    printf("sucessfully opened at fd=%d\n", fd);

}
```

`setitimer` or `timer_create`/`timer_settime` provide better more fine grained timers than `alarm`. They also have the possibility of setting the timer to repeat which allows you to resignal in case the first signal "missed" (i.e., ran just before the `open` call was entered and so failed to break the potentially indefinitely blocking syscall).